# sql left join criteria in join vs where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing query to select some payments

I want to filter out any payments that are for clients that have an active alert in another table called ClientAlert

So I figured I would do a left join and check if the ClientAlertId is null.

```
select      * 
from        payments p
left join   client c on c.clientid = p.clientid
left join   ClientAlert ca on ca.CRMId = c.CRMId and ca.ClientAlertSubjectId = 1 and ca.IsActive = 1 and (ca.ExpiryDate is null or ca.ExpiryDate > GetDate())
where       
            ca.clientalertid is null and            
            p.PaymentStatusId = 2 and 
            p.PaymentDate <= GetDate() and 
            p.PaymentCategoryId = 1
```

This seems to work I think

But I have two questions:

1. Could there ever be a scenario that would cause multiple payments to be returned instead of one by adding this join?
2. when I specified the following in the where clause instead of the join, it did not give the same results and I dont understand why

   and ca.ClientAlertSubjectId = 1 and ca.IsActive = 1 and (ca.ExpiryDate is null or ExpiryDate > GetDate())

I thought having that criteria in the where clause woiuld be equivelent to having it in the join

Comment: `I thought having that criteria in the where clause woiuld be equivelent to having it in the join`, that might be true for an `INNER JOIN`, but it's absolutely false for an `OUTER JOIN`

Comment: Please edit your question and qualify the column names with table aliaes.  For outer joins, it makes a big difference where the columns come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If they can have multiple alerts, theoretically. However since you are excluding payments with alerts, this should not be a problem. If you were including them it could be. If this was a problem, you should use a "not in" subquery instead of left outer join since that can cause duplicate records if it's not 1:1.
2. Having criteria in the where clause excludes the entire row if it doesn't match the criteria. Having it in the join clause means the joined record is not shown but the "parent" is.

Comment: they can and do have multiple alerts - but I thought that because I'm filtering to those **without** an alert (by ca.ClientAlertId = null), that this wouldnt cause duplicate payments?

Comment: Okay, then it won't cause duplicates since you are filtering those out.

Comment: One more thing is that performance may be significantly better if you do "not in" instead of this approach. While it will work, in a quick test in a big database I have, it was 10 times faster to use "not in". YMMV

Answer (score 2):

1. You could get multiples per payment record if it links to more than one Client record. Based on the WHERE clause though, I don't see how multiple ClientAlert records could cause duplication.
2. `LEFT JOIN` records return NULLs across all their columns when there is no match. Adding `ca.ClientAlertSubjectId = 1 and ca.IsActive = 1` to the WHERE clause basically forces that join to behave like an INNER JOIN because it would HAVE to find a matching record, but I'm guessing it would never return data because ClientAlertId is a non-nullable column. So basically you created a query where you need a NULL row (indicating there are no alerts), but the row must contain data.

Comment: they can and do have multiple alerts - but I thought that because I'm filtering to those **without** an alert (by ca.ClientAlertId = null), that this wouldnt cause duplicate payments?

Answer (score 1):

```
select      * 
from        payments p
left join   client c on c.clientid = p.clientid
left join   ClientAlert ca on ca.CRMId = c.CRMId 
and ca.ClientAlertSubjectId = 1 and ca.IsActive = 1 
and (ca.ExpiryDate is null or ca.ExpiryDate > GetDate())
where       
            ca.CRMId is null and            
            p.PaymentStatusId = 2 and 
            p.PaymentDate <= GetDate() and 
            p.PaymentCategoryId = 1
```

1. This tiny change will assure you will never get any duplicates IF clientid is unique in table client
2. Moving conditions from left join to where means you are moving the left join condition into a condition for the row. So if the condition is not met, the row is not returned.
   Left join condition will always include the row from left side of the join

Answer (score 0):

First, unless there are payments that aren't associated with a client, then the first join should be an inner join.

Second, once a client has the proper alert, you filter out *all* payments made by that client, even those made months or years before the alert took effect. Is that what you want?

Third and last (though this is a long one): an outer join has this format:

```
select   ...
from     InnerTable i
left [outer] join OuterTable o
    on  <join criteria>
where   <filter criteria>;
```

For outer joins only, it is important that all checks involving the outer table should be consider as join criteria. At a bear minimum, there will be

```
    on  o.JoinField = i.OtherJoinField
```

or in your case

```
    on ca.CRMId = c.CRMId
```

To keep the output that is expected of an outer join, checks of other outer table fields should also go in the ON clause as additional join criteria:

```
    on  ca.CRMId = c.CRMId
    and ca.ClientAlertSubjectId = 1
    and ca.IsActive = 1
    and (ca.ExpiryDate is null or ca.ExpiryDate > GetDate())
```

Adding those addition checks to the WHERE clause will, as you discovered, completely filter out all the benefits of the outer join to deliver the same result set as an inner join.

However, you could get the output to return to the outer join result set by making one little change:

```
where   (ca.clientalertid is null
         or (ca.ClientAlertSubjectId = 1
             and ca.IsActive = 1
             and (ca.ExpiryDate is null or ca.ExpiryDate > GetDate()))
    and p.PaymentStatusId = 2
    and ...
```

But this doesn't *quite* get back to a normal outer join result set. In your case, the regular outer join will show payment and client data with NULLs for alert data for:

1. Payments by clients with no alerts at all.
2. Payments by clients with alerts but not fully qualified by the additional criteria. For example, if IsActive contains 0.

Then there would be alert data for those payments by clients who have a fully qualified alert.

Moving the additional criteria to the WHERE clause but in the format shown above will show payment and client data with NULLs for alert data *only* for payments with no alerts at all, along with alert data for fully qualified alerts. The payments and clients with alerts not fully qualified would not show up at all.

Remember that. There may be times when that is exactly what you want.

But that does not appear to be what you want at this time. If you want to see no alerts and partial alerts but filter out the fully qualified alerts, you can't place the other criteria in the WHERE clause. Your original query is the only way to do that.

There really is no reason to be placing the additional criteria in the WHERE clause. It gets you nothing. There is no performance benefit to be gained from it even for the inner join where it doesn't effect the output. Compare the execution plan for the inner joins with the additional criteria in the ON clause and in the WHERE clause. They are identical. The same comparison for outer joins are different. In fact, with the addition criteria in the WHERE clause, the execution plan is identical to those of the inner joins.

So just use the query you have and be satisfied that you are getting the output you want.